# How to combine two filters in search api views?

Tags: 8, views, search

I have a search index which is indexing both content and files.

I have configured the search api views which displays the search results.

On this view, I have a filter on type which displays the content types as links using better exposed filter.

Is there any way to add another option to the same filter `files` but clicking on it will display files in the search results only.

Is it possible? Any custom solution hint?

I have tried the combined global filter but that only works with fields not with rendered entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an aggregated field of search api. And combined the `Content: content type` and `Media: bundle` fields.

And used that field in the search api views filter.

But the filter was a text field. So to display it as links, I have created a  custom views filter for that aggregated field.